# Deploy docker image from dockerhub to kubenetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, image, kubernetes

Can anny one suggest how to deploy docker image from public repository to kubernestes using yaml?

I have no idea, but need to deply the docker image in kubernestes cluster.

Comment: It should be enough to put the image's name in the `image:` part of your Deployment spec.  Are you having trouble with this?  Do you have a YAML file and a specific error you can include in the question?

Comment: There are plenty of documents on this. There are different types of yaml files which you can write.

Comment: Hi Bharat thnaks for your reply, can you share one if you have.

Comment: Hello David: the yaml file is  :                    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcatinfra
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: tomcatinfra
      labels:
        app: tomcatinfra
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: harsha2018/tomcat1
        name: tomcatapp

Answer (score 0):

If you use a deployment, statefulset, daemonset, pod ect. the `image: nginx:1.14.2` will check the docker hub to pull the docker image. If you use another public repository for example the google docker repository just add the hostname like this `image: gcr.io/google-containers/busybox:latest`. Most of the time there is a pull command button that shows you the full docker image name with the tag. Like [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/global/busybox).

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```